# ImageMagick/Convert - SVG opacity not taken into account

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert the SVG file below with ImageMagick's convert to an PNG file. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to call convert so that the opacity value of the rectangle is taken into account. When I open the svg with inkscape and save it as png the opacity value is used so I assume the svg file is correct. (The reason I want to use "convert" is that inkscape is not installed on the server I am using) I use convert right now in the most simple way, any additional parameters I tried did not have any positive effect (convert first time user...)

```
convert test-alpha.svg test-alpha.png
```

Thanks buddies

martin

UPDATE: tested on OSX Mountain Lion, ImageMagick 6.8.8-3 Q16 x86_64 2014-02-19 (installed via mac ports)

UPDATE2: Just tried it on a linux machine and, as nwellnhof already commented, it does it correct there. So it seems a particular OSX related problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="qi-svg" class="quote-image" width="640" height="480" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;">

<rect id="background" width="150" height="300" style="opacity: 1;fill: #aa0000" transform="translate(200,0)" />
<rect id="background" width="150" height="300" style="opacity: 0.1;fill: #aa0000" />

</svg>
```

1) correct png via inkscape
2) png via convert

[image: Correct png (via inkscape)]
[image: convert....]

Comment: Can you include your OS and the version of ImageMagick in your post?

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 13.10 (ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 using rsvg-convert 2.36.4).

Comment: oh sorry I should mention of course - OSX Mountain Lion, ImageMagick 6.8.8-3 Q16 x86_64 2014-02-19

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled ImageMagick on OSX with the following ports command

```
sudo port install imagemagick +rsvg
```

and it works now, the +rsvg made the trick.